# Сортировка массива по заданной дате

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, qsort

У меня есть массив такого типа:

```
Array ( 
[15709] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15709 
  [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 00:30:00 
  [program_info] => Х/ф "Стелла" ) 
[15710] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15710 [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 02:20:00 
  [program_info] => Х/ф "Часы доблести" ) 
[15711] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15711 
  [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 06:15:00 
  [program_info] => Фильм-концерт "Хичкок. Концерт в магазине" 
) )
```

Мне его нужно отсортировать по полю `[date]` так что бы сначала шли все элементы у которых поле `[date]` больше 05:00:00, тоесть массив имел тако вид :

```
Array ( 
    [15711] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15711 
      [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 06:15:00 
      [program_info] => Фильм-концерт "Хичкок. Концерт в магазине" )
    [15709] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15709 
      [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 00:30:00 
      [program_info] => Х/ф "Стелла")
    [15710] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15710 [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 02:20:00 
      [program_info] => Х/ф "Часы доблести"
    ) )
```

Comment: >что бы сначала шли все элементы у которых поле [date] больше 05:00:00. Что вы имеет в виду под больше 5 утра? Если по убыванию не устраивает, то уточните пожалуйста ваш вопрос. Т.к. это могут быть разные дни '2016-03-20 06:00:00', '2016-03-21 02:00:00', что должно быть после сортировки?

Comment: @jekaby в моем случае дни одинаковые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// $arr - ваш массив

usort($arr, function ($arr1, $arr2) {
    return $arr1['date'] < $arr2['date'];
});

var_dump($arr);
```

отсортирует по убыванию 'date'. Если везде в 'date' timestamp, то строковое сравнение ок отработает.

**UPD**: если хотите сохранить ключи исходного массива, то замените функцию usort на uasort. [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).

Comment: по такой структуре `array('05:00','06:00','07:00','12:00','14:00','16:00','22:00','23:00','02:00','‌​04:00')`