# Сортировка по дате в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01.09.2016
            [sum] => 450
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 31.08.2016
            [sum] => 156
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.09.2016
            [sum] => 888
        )

)
```

Хочу сделать сортировку по дате, как её правильно сделать?

Comment: Откуда берется массив?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506611/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b) 
{
    if ($a["date"] == $b["date"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a["date"]) < strtotime($b["date"])) ? -1 : 1;
}
$a = Array(
      Array("date" => "01.09.2016", "sum" => "450"),
      Array("date" => "31.08.2016", "sum" => "156"),
      Array("date" => "02.09.2016","sum" => "888"));

usort($a, "cmp");
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 8):

Так как решение через usort уже предложили, предложу решение через array_multisort, которое будет быстрее на больших обьемах данных, но требует извлечения колонки из исходного массива, но можно выбрать еще одну колонку и отсортировать по второй исходный массив.

```
$dateArray = [];

foreach($yourArray as $key=>$arr){
    $dateArray[$key]=$arr['date'];
}

array_multisort($dateArray, SORT_STRING, $yourArray);

var_dump($yourArray);
```

Проверено на локальной машине, 100 000 элементов сортировалось 1 секунду 20 мс через usort, а через array_multisort 280 мс.