# Как отсортировать 1 массив по данным из другого массива laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть все пользователи, кроме авторизованного

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Есть личные сообщения

Нужно для каждого пользователя вывести его последнее сообщение

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $message = Chat::where([
    ['owner', '=', Auth::id()],
    ['to', '=', $user->id],
  ])->first();
  $user['mess'] = $message->message;
}
```

Теперь у нас есть данные о пользователе и его последнее сообщение

Теперь нужно реализовать порядок пользователей, то есть сейчас сортировка пользователей и их вывод сделана по id пользователя, а мне нужно, чтобы он сортировал по последнему сообщению(как в вк), у кого последнее сообщение(по дате) тот вверху

Пробовал сделать сортировку, [СО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564300/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5/564314)

```
$dateArray = [];

foreach($yourArray as $key=>$arr){
    $dateArray[$key]=$arr['date'];
}

array_multisort($dateArray, SORT_STRING, $yourArray);

var_dump($yourArray);
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой, что laravel выдает дату в объекте

```
{"date":"2018-10-08 07:16:55.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}
```

И не получается достать из него дату

Как это исправить? Может есть более простой способ?

Comment: а в чем проблема сортировку сделать сразу в запросе получения сообщений?

Comment: @Manitikyl Немного не понял Вашу мысль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

можно так:

```
User::all()->except(Auth::id())->get();
```

Можно отсортировать пользователей прямо в запросе:

```
User::all()->except(Auth::id())->orderByDesc('my_date')->get();
```

Вот так одним запросом можно получить все сообщения:

```
// получить массив id пользователей [1, 2, 3...]
$usersId = $users->pluck('id');
// получить сообщения пользователей
$messages = Chat::where('owner', Auth::id())->whereIn('to', $usersId)->get();
```

Жаль что в laravel нет способа обновить всех пользователей одним запросом.

Придется обновлять через цикл:

```
// перебирает сообщения
$messages->each($function ($message) use ($users) {
    // получить владельца сообщения
    $owner = $users->firstWhere('id', $message->owner);
    // изменить message у пользователя
    $owner->message = $message->message;
    $owner->save();
});
```

Или так:

```
$message->each($function ($message) use ($users) {
    // получить владельца сообщения
    $owner = $users->firstWhere('id', $message->owner);
    // изменить message у пользователя
    $owner->fill(['message' = $message->message]);
});
```

Надеюсь, что помог.

Answer (score 1):

Ну сортировку по `DateTime()` можно сделать так:

```
$array = [
    ['date' => new DateTime('10/15/2018'), 'text' => '1'],
    ['date' => new DateTime('10/16/2018'), 'text' => '2'],
    ['date' => new DateTime('10/14/2018'), 'text' => '3'],
    ['date' => new DateTime('10/17/2018'), 'text' => '4']
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a["date"] != $b["date"]) ? ($a["date"] > $b["date"]) ? -1 : 1 : 0;
});

var_dump($array);
```