# Вывод информации из двух таблиц последовательно

Tags: php

Есть две таблицы по  клиентам, в одной таблице информация о покупках, в другой о ремонтах.
Нужно чтобы в карте каждого клиента выводилась информация последовательно и по ремонтам и по покупкам. Сегодня он сделал ремонт, завтра купил и все его действия выводятся в одно окно. Использовать JOIN или выводить информацию из двух таблиц (SELECT * FROM action a, sale s  WHERE a.card_id='$search' OR s.card_id ='$search') не получается, потому что таблицы объединяются, а нужно именно последовательное выведение по дате и времени. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Достать данные из двух таблиц. обеденить их в один масив а потом осортировать по дате

```
function cmp($a, $b) 
{
    if ($a["date"] == $b["date"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a["date"]) < strtotime($b["date"])) ? -1 : 1;
}
$a = Array(
      Array("date" => "01.09.2016", "sum" => "450"),
      Array("date" => "31.08.2016", "sum" => "156"),
      Array("date" => "02.09.2016","sum" => "888"));

usort($a, "cmp");
var_dump($a);
```

код сортировки взят от сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564314/280621

Comment: Думаю сортировку лучше сделать средствами самого sql, если заказов будет очень много, то php будет очень долго его сортировать + жрать дофига ресурсов

Comment: ваш ответ не очень соответствует вопросу ватора.

Comment: Вопрос тоже не очень корректен. Сортировка по дате даст то, что, вроде бы, хочет автора вопроса. Но! Что делать, если даты совпали? И вообще, что приоритетнее при выводе - ремонты или покупки? Если автору нужно чтобы вначале выводились ремонты ( по дате), а потом покупки (по дате) или общий список как бы он ни шел отсортированный по дате?